# Hotspot collection. But balance is not changing in the wallet

Tags: transaction

My Hotspot device is collecting ok and i am able to connect and receive collected iot. But my balance is not changing in the wallet. What's happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean when using Helium hotspot and the app? Do you see the balance on your account if you check using the explorer?